# Two onClick functions on a react component, doesn't fire up

Tags: reactjs

I've got a component where I want 2 onClicks to happen,
I figured I need to get to out to a separate function but when I wrote that and tried giving it as an onClick I get errors, primary one being that I passed down an object.

Can you please guide me how would I write that properly?

The `onCategoryChange` function doesn't fire, and `closeSideMenu` doesn't matter on large screens since the menu is always open.

```
export  function SingleNavLink(props){
    const {url,name,iconPath,onCategoryChange,closeSideMenu}=props
    const IsAllowedToCloseMenue=(closeSideMenu===undefined)? '':{ onClick: () => {closeSideMenu()}}

    const linkProps= (onCategoryChange===undefined) ? {exact: true, to: url} : { onClick: () => {onCategoryChange(name.toLowerCase())}}

    return(
        <NavLink  {...linkProps} {...IsAllowedToCloseMenue}>
          {name}
        </NavLink>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a onClick handler, as @Mikhal Sidorov says, and then check if each is undefined in a `if` with `||` to see if either `closeSideMenu` or `onCategoryChange` is undefined. If it is undefined, then execute the *function*.

Answer (score 0):

You should make one onClick handler, and check conditions inside handler. Example:

```
const linkProps = (onCategoryChange === undefined) ? {exact: true, to: url} : null

const handleClick = () => {
    if (closeSideMenu === undefined) {
        closeSideMenu()
    }
    if (onCategoryChange === undefined) {
        onCategoryChange(name.toLowerCase())
    }
}

return (
    <NavLink onClick={handleClick} {...linkProps}>
        {name}
    </NavLink>
)
```

Comment: Your conditions will cause errors, because undefined is not a function...